# Log errors from hystrix commands

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix

With the @HystrixCommand annotation there can be configured a fallback method which should run in case that the method fails.

```
    public Link defaultDogeLink(Account account) {
         return null;
    }

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultDogeLink")
    public Link buildDogeLink(Account account) {
         // some code that may throw Runtime Exceptions
    }
```

What should I do in order to log (in a central class) the runtime exceptions thrown in all the methods annotated with @HystrixCommand ?

I am using spring-cloud-netflix and not vanilla hystrix-javanica.
I am looking for something similar to org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler class (for Spring's @Async) that i need to implement in my application.

In hystrix-core, the HystrixCommand class has the method [getFailedExecutionException()](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#getFailedExecutionException()) which can be used within the fallback method for logging the exception. Can somebody maybe point me how to get this exception when working with hystrix-javanica?

Comment: Plain Hystrix allows you to register a HystrixCommandExecutionHook using HystrixPlugins.getInstance().registerCommandExecutionHook(). I have no experience in a Spring environment with this, but you might want to give it a try.

Comment: @marius_neo is right, `@HystrixCommand` is vanilla `hystrix-javanica`, there are no spring extensions to it right now, so give his advice a try.

Answer (score 3):

I found within the unit tests of hystrix-javanica the a way to get the last executed hystrix command:

```
public Link defaultDogeLink(Account account) {
     LOG.warn("exception occured while building doge link for account " + account, getCommand().getFailedExecutionException());
     return null;
}

@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultDogeLink")
public Link buildDogeLink(Account account) {
     // some code that may throw Runtime Exceptions
}  


private com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixInvokableInfo<?> getCommand() {
    return HystrixRequestLog.getCurrentRequest().getAllExecutedCommands().iterator().next();
}
```

It is a bit more verbose than expected, but fulfills my requirement.